# Is it possible to run the address locator in ArcGIS via Python?

Tags: arcpy, geocoding

I have a question regarding the address locator in ArcGIS.

It is possible to create an address locator by using Python, but is it also possible to run an address locator via Python?

This means, is there any Python code that does the same as the address locator toolbar in ArcGIS?

The code should get the address by an user and should then locate the address and zoom on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [GeocodeAddresses_geocoding](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002600000006000000.htm). I'm personally still trying to get it to work, so if you get it, feel free to share!

Comment: I will give it a try, it seems to be the most promising solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

[Create address locator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Address_Locator/002600000004000000/)

Once you have an address event layer you could create a python add-in that queries/selects features ([Select Layer By Attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000)) then zooms (use Data Frame method - [zoomToSelectedFeatures ()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000003000000)) to the selected features.

Comment: But this is the code to create an address locator. Is there a way to give the python code an address and the code then searches for the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is direct way to do what you are wanting to do.  If you have an address layer then you could query for the text, then just zoom to the feature.  The only option I believe you have is to use an address locater web service to pass the address and get back XYs, then you could just zoom on the XYs.